# Dart Route URLPattern base url

Tags: regex, dart

When running the [Dart Route Client example](https://github.com/dart-lang/route/blob/master/example/client.dart) I get an error:

`Illegal argument(s): No handler found for /MYAPP/web/myapp.html`
which makes sense since the default example defines the URLS as

```
library example.urls;

final one = new UrlPattern('/one');
final two = new UrlPattern('/two');
final home = new UrlPattern('/');
```

and the Routes are then handled:

```
 import 'urls.dart' as urls;
 ...
 var router = new Router()
    ..addHandler(urls.one, showOne)
    ..addHandler(urls.two, showTwo)
    ..addHandler(urls.home, (_) => null)
    ..listen();
```

Given that my application will have different base URLs depending on what environment it is being run in (Local, Development, Test, Production) and those URLS will look like this

```
http://MYAPP/web/index.html
http://dev.mydomain.com/alpha/index.html
http://dev.mydomain.com/index.html
http://dev.mydomain.com
http://test.mydomain.com/index.html
http://test.mydomain.com
http://mydomain.com/index.html
http://mydomain.com
```

How can I define the expression in my URLPatterns to avoid having to rename them depending on the environment.  Specifically how can I define a "home" url that represents the root of my hierarchy knowing that I will use root+hash to represent places other than home.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like some code in the example server wasn't yet updated for Dart 1.0, so the server wouldn't have run and the example requires a server since it uses pushState. I pushed a fix to version 0.4.6.

To run the example, run server.dart and then navigate Dartium to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. If you want to run it in another browser you have to compile client.html with dart2js first.

Comment: The client code works fine but my question was more about how to create a URLPattern on the client side so that it does not need to be updated whenever I redeploy.  I am looking for behavior similar to Angular's $RouteProvider http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider  It may be there and I am simply unaware of how to create the right regex.

Comment: The client code only works correctly when run with the example server, which would have run recently due to SDK breakage. That's what the initial problem of "No handler found for /MYAPP/web/myapp.html" was, you were mostly likely launching the client example directly from the Editor. As for prefixes, it's the Angular $location service that knows  of the initial URL the app is loaded from, but that strategy is inherently incompatible with a pushState based system, since the app can be initially loaded from any URL, not just the root URL. The root URL will need to be part of some configuration.

Comment: I think I may be asking the question wrong.  I browsed the other branches in repository and it looks like both hierarchical and 0.5.0 do exactly what I want on the client side.  I get the feeling that the imminent release of Dart 1.0 is playing a part in this and that I should just stick with the experimental route-hierarchical until the waters settle.

Comment: Can you describe what it is that they do that you want? I'm working on 0.5.0 right now and want to understand how it's different for you.

Comment: I think you are already adding it in 0.5.0.  1) Client side routing not dependent on a server. 2)  A "default" or fallback route.  3) Nested routing. 4) (Don't shoot the messenger) more complete documentation. 5) (important) A way to ignore the base url so that I do not need to rewrite the code to identify the root URL.  https://github.com/dart-lang/route/tree/0.5.0 in the README.md seems to describe just such a thing.  If you don't mind saying so in an answer I will gladly mark it accepted.

Comment: #5 is what we don't have in any of the branches, because it requires some knowledge of what the root URL of the app is. AngularJS's $location service infers this from the first URL used to access the app, but I don't see how that works where you could deep link into a single page app that uses pushState. I really think there has to be some deployment configuration for the root URL. If you have a suggestion to get around that I'm all ears! :)

Comment: I see the problem then.  I guess I can manage it as a configuration term I hold in a statically served json file.  I use this technique for all those variables that are deployment dependent anyway.  Will you write the gist of our conversation and rewrite your answer so I can mark it accepted?  I hate leaving questions hanging without an official answer.

Comment: Sure, I'll also work on an example that mounts the app someplace other than the root URL. Thanks for talking it out with me!

Comment: Bump to remind you to answer this when you release 0.5.0 so it isn't hanging unanswered.